# How do I make a div relative to a table header (th) but outside of it?

Tags: html, css, html-table, orientation

I have a table header that will show a help text (div) when clicking on it.

But the help div always make the table header larger than the other headers.

The code snippet is below:

```css
#help_box {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--The content of the site-->
  <div id="contentv2">

    <div id="highlight">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 130px;">Stock</th>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 70px;">Price</th>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 70px;">Variation<div id="help_box" align="justify">The period os ocilation is a random text. To make % of it is is the same size and the last week (until Sunday 23:59).</div></th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The first row</td><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$75.50</td><td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td></tr>
          <tr><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The second row</td><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$66.50</td><td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td></tr>
          <tr><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The third row</td><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$56.50</td><td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How I need it to be:

The help box should be positioned right below the header and overlap the rows below, but shouldn't mess with the size of the table header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should apply `position: absolute` to your `#help_box` div. Then you can position it with `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` properties.

If you want your positioning applied relatively to the table, not the entire page, you have to give `position: relative` property to the table.

Comment: It worked. But I've had to use "position: relative" to a distant parent  'div' ! Didn't know that position relative-absolute relation between components.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking the following should give you what you need (Although the size of the menu will grow vertically so you'll need to be sure to limit the contents based on the width of the header)

```css
#help_box {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--The content of the site-->
  <div id="contentv2">

    <div id="highlight">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 130px;">Stock</th>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 70px;">Price</th>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 70px; position: relative">Variation<div id="help_box" align="justify">The period os ocilation is a random text. To make % of it is is the same size and the last week (until Sunday 23:59).</div></th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The first row</td><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$75.50</td><td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td></tr>
          <tr><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The second row</td><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$66.50</td><td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td></tr>
          <tr><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The third row</td><td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$56.50</td><td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It worked! Fiddle below:

```css
#help_box {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--The content of the site-->
  <div id="contentv2" style="position: relative">

    <div id="highlight">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 130px;">Stock</th>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 70px;">Price</th>
            <th valign="center" style="min-width: 70px;">Variation
              <div id="help_box" align="justify">The period os ocilation is a random text. To make % of it is is the same size and the last week (until Sunday 23:59).</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The first row</td>
            <td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$75.50</td>
            <td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The second row</td>
            <td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$66.50</td>
            <td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 16.66px;">The third row</td>
            <td style="font-size: 16.66px;">$56.50</td>
            <td align="right" style="font-size: 16.66px;color:red">-0.66%</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```